# How to invoke the Flow, On Button Click from LWC(Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I have requirement where I have to load flow having different screens, on click of button in LWC.

I found only one blog related to this is :

https://unofficialsf.com/developer-topic-insert-screen-flows-into-your-lwc/

but not working for me. Please help me on it, how we can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `lightning-flow-support` LWC component?
The [component documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation).
I've also found a [usage example](https://www.salesforcebolt.com/2022/04/navigation-in-flow-using-lightning-web-component.html).

Comment: Thanks for the responce, this i haven't tried as  I have modal and a button, once I will click on that flow screen as to come and all other action will be on flow screen.  Let me try out this way also.

Comment: Did you able to solve it?